# Space usage procedure oracle for an input table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any space usage display procedure in oracle for an input table like sp_space_used in sql server...

Comment: Don't expect it to do it "like SQL Server".  Oracle and MSSQL are profoundly different in their architecture - which would impact any sort of space usage analysis.  As long as you expect to approach Oracle while wearing your Microsoft goggles, you can expect less than optimal results.  "When in Rome . . . "

Comment: If your "use case" is to "blindly follow" a procedure that doesn't apply to the architecture, then there's nothing that can be added.  Would you "blindly follow" a procedure to adjust the fuel injectors on an all-electric car?

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of all tables the current user owns, you can query [`user_segments`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/USER_SEGMENTS.html) but it's a bit tricky to bring together all the different segment types properly.

I think the following returns the correct size information (but I might have missed some combinations, e.g. I am not sure if index organized tables are handled correctly):

```
with size_info as (
  select case 
            when sg.segment_type in ('INDEX','LOBINDEX') then ix.table_name
            when sg.segment_type = 'LOBSEGMENT' then ul.table_name
            else sg.segment_name
         end as table_name,
         sg.segment_type,
         sg.bytes / 1024 / 1024 as size_mb
  from user_segments sg
    left join user_indexes ix on sg.segment_name = ix.index_name and sg.segment_type in ('INDEX', 'INDEX PARTITION', 'LOBINDEX')
    left join user_lobs ul on sg.segment_name = ul.segment_name and sg.segment_type = 'LOBSEGMENT'
) 
select table_name, 
       sum(case when segment_type in ('TABLE', 'LOBSEGMENT', 'TABLE PARTITION') then size_mb end) as table_size_mb,
       sum(case when segment_type in ('INDEX', 'INDEX PARTITION', 'LOBINDEX') then size_mb end) as index_size_mb
from size_info 
group by table_name;
```

I don't know what "reserved" or "unused" is supposed to be.

The "number of rows" could be retrieved from `user_tables.num_rows` but that's just an estimate from the last time the statistics were updated.

Of course you can add a where clause to restrict that query to just one table.

---

If you insist on making things more complicated than needed and want to use an unnecessary stored procedure instead of running a simple SQL query, then you can put the above into a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure get_table_statistics
as
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;  
BEGIN
  OPEN c1 FOR 
    .... the query from above ...;

  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c1);
END;
/
```

Comment: @rock_techie: again: **why** a procedure? A plain SQL script is much easier to use. In Oracle, procedures are very rarely used to return results. That's what queries are for if you want to encapsulate the query, use a view. If you are migrating from SQL Server, stop doing things the "SQL Server way" - Oracle is very different and usually works better if you don't force unusual habits on it (e.g. the excessive use of temp tables)

Comment: @rock_techie: use a view then so that the code doesn't need to know about the actual query. A procedure is the wrong choice for this in Oracle. Believe me.

Comment: There is no way you can run an application that was designed for SQL Server without changes with Oracle. You have to change the application at some point, there is no way around it - if at least introducing an abstraction layer for different DBMS products.  Rather than creating clumsy, slow and hard-to-maintain hacks everywhere, start with those changes now. I am pretty sure if you insist on doing everything the "SQL Server" way your migration will fail (or at least you will be left with an application that performs poorly)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK no. But you can build your own by querying the tables user_segments, user_extents, user_indexes and user_tab_statistics.

I recommend you to familiarize with the [Oracle logical storage structure](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/logical-storage-structures.html#GUID-13CE5EDA-8C66-4CA0-87B5-4069215A368D).

In practice, you can forget about table extents allocation and focus in TABLESPACEs allocation and fragmentation.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am suggesting. You can create your own stored procedure. If you don't know how, maybe you should start reading https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tdddg/index.html and https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admqs/index.html